# I'll Sleep now vs I'll go to sleep now

Tags: sentence-usage

While talking to a friend over phone if I am feeling sleepy and before hanging up I want to convey to my friend that I want to sleep now. How should I say that?

Comment: You could try "Now I must climb the wooden hill" and see what reaction you get.

Answer (score 2):

You should say, "I'm going to bed now", or perhaps "It's been great talking to you, but I'm getting a little tired and I think I'm going to go to bed now."

You shouldn't say "I'll sleep now", nor "I'll go to sleep now" - it just sounds a bit odd to use *will* here.

Comment: There are some informal expressions that can be used as well, like "catch some z's" (for a nap) or "hit the hay" (for going to bed for the night).